# Error cannot convert from 'out string' to 'out int'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing my first registration form in **ASP.NET MVC** and I am presenting the following error

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out string' to 'out int'

```
var ticketPriorityInput = "ALTO";

if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"], out ticketPriorityInput) == false)
{        
}
```

[image: image error]

`ticketPriorityInput` is of type `string`

I do this because I need to validate that when the `ticketPriorityInput` field is saved to save it by default with the string "ALTO", you can tell me how it is the best way to do it or how I can fix it

I explain better a form but depending on the session variables certain fields are loaded, `ticketPriorityInput` has to go in both one and the other, the difference is that in which I need also goes `ticketPriorityInput` but it is not being entered I need it to be stored by default value "ALTO"

Comment: The second parameter is expecting an integer. That variable on the second parameter would be the output (assuming it is able to convert the first parmeter to an int)

Comment: In C# you can't store two different types of data in one variable (unlss it's a `dynamic`, but then you can't pass a `dynamic` to `TryParse()` either). So if you want to use two different types of data you must use two different variables.

Comment: You've explained the *business rule* with the edit but you haven't provide any useful technical details.

Comment: @madreflection Review the question again, add what I need to do

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need `ticketPriorityInput` to have two different kinds of data. Why can't you store the `int` value in it, and if the conversion is unsuccessful, later on whenever you need just use "ALTO" and pass it to wherever you want.

Comment: I had *already* reviewed it and, as I pointed out, you added business rule information but you haven't added any useful technical details. For example, you haven't said where you're storing the int-or-string value; I can only infer that it's a database table based on the error message you stated, and "ALTO" is just 4 characters so either the column is smaller than that or there's something else going on. We don't have enough information to help with any of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments of all users and none understood what my question was saying despite being updated with a clearer explanation I found the solution to my problem in this way

```
var ticketPriorityInput = Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"];
var ticketPriorityInputByDefault = "ALTO";

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ticketPriorityInput)){
   ticketPriorityInput = ticketPriorityInputByDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

var ticketPriorityInput is explicity a string because you initialized it to a string.

try:

```
var ticketPriorityInput = 0;

if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"], out ticketPriorityInput) == false)
{
}
```

if you dont want to change ticketPriorityInput, create a different variable that is an int for ticketPriorityInput to save to.

Comment: Initializing it this way prevents the compiler from detecting when it's uninitialized. This is more of an issue when combining `int.TryParse` with additional conditions. It's better to declare it without initialization, `int ticketPriorityInput;` or better still, use `int.Parse(..., out int ticketPriorityInput)`.

Comment: Remember that I must send by default the value "ALTO" no 0

Comment: @SebastianSalazar You should edit your question to explain how you intend to mix string and integer values.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *terribletp* has answered your question about the error you're getting (and even addressed your comment, if you read it carefully enough). The fact that you want to do something that doesn't make sense without additional information is a separate matter. You should accept this answer and write a new question with detail about what you're doing with the input and why. Often times, you get advice on a better way to do something because the bigger picture is understood.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert the value of `Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"]` to `int` and save the result in `ticketPriorityInput` if successful, and if not successful, you want `ticketPriorityInput` to contain the string `"ALTO"`.

So you would still have to use two variables; there's no way getting around the requirement to pass an `int` to the `int.TryParse()` method. But you can make `ticketPriorityInput` into type `dynamic` and use this:

```
dynamic ticketPriorityInput = "ALTO";

if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"], out int tInt))
{
    ticketPriorityInput = tInt;
}
```

Now, if the conversion is successful `ticketPriorityInput` will contain the converted `integer`, otherwise the value `"ALTO"`.

Comment: When I try it that way you give me the model generates an error and it is the following `SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: @SebastianSalazar: Like I said, you need to provide more information. This (the column length) is a hidden detail that, had we known it, could have informed an answer that would actually solve your problem.

Comment: It appears that you haven't quite figured out the requirements of your program or how to properly design it. First thing; you MUST pass an `int` to the `int.TryParse()` method, there's no way around it. So you're going to have to use an `int` variable for that. Two; only `dynamic` type in C# can contain two different types of data, so if you insist on storing two different kinds of data in one variable (which I still don't understand why you want to do that), then you're going to have to use `dynamic`. I don't know where this new error is getting, but that is a different question to this one.

Comment: @Sach Review the question again, add what I need to do